# Aggregate is not a function mongoose js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

how are you?, I'm trying to find one field of client with out seeing the entire Document, only the field I want.

This is my code:

```
app.get('/api/clients/adress/:street', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const street = req.body.street;
        const address = await Client.findOne({'clients.address.street': street});
        street.aggregate([ 
             { "$lookup": {
                 from: 'clients',
                 localField: 'address.street',
              // foreignField: '_id',
                 as: 'street'
                          }
             },
             { "$unwind" : '$clients'},
             { "$match" : 
             { "clients.address.street" : street } 
             } 
               ]);

              if (address) {
                 res.send(address);
                  } else {
                    res
                   .status(404)
                   .send({ message: `Client's Address '${id}' not found.` });
                         }
                         } catch (e) {
                      res.status(500).send({ mensaje: `Internal Server Error.\n\n${e}` });
                         }
                               });
```

And I find the next message on postman: "aggregate is not a function". ¿What's the error?

Help me, please

Comment: You need to add aggregate to the findOne query

Comment: I did this way:   const address = await Client.findOne({'clients.address.street': street}.aggregate([ 
        { "$lookup": {
           from: 'clients',
           localField: 'address.street',
          // foreignField: '_id',
           as: 'address'
         }
       },
         { "$unwind" : '$clients'},
         { "$match" : 
             { "clients.address.street" : street } 
         } 
     ]));
     I've got this same error: "aggregate is not a function"

Comment: We use aggregate with model and Please tell me street is model ?

Comment: no, it's not. street is not a model

Comment: Please use aggregate function with model